# Неправильно обработан случай нескольких строк максимальной длины

Tags: c++, for, vector

**Задание:** "В векторе строк some_vector найдите самую длинную строку и её индекс. Выведите её в соответствии с форматом выходных данных. ***Если несколько строк имеют одинаковую длину, выведите первую из них.***"

При проверке кода выводится ошибка:

*"причина: Неправильный ответ*

*подсказка: Неправильно обработан случай нескольких строк максимальной длины."*

Сам код:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    
    int main() {
        std::vector<std::string> some_vector = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
        int longest_index = 0;
        int current_index = 0;
        int siz = some_vector[longest_index].size();
        for (std::string el : some_vector) {
            int siz1 = el.size();
            if (siz1 > siz) {
                longest_index = current_index;
            }
            current_index += 1;
        }
        std::cout << "Longest string \"" << some_vector[longest_index] << "\" at index " << longest_index;
    }
```

Подскажите, в чём именно ошибка(

При собственных проверках проблемы со строками одной длины не возникает.

**UPD: проблема решена:** переменную siz нужно объявлять в цикле for, чтобы siz менялась вместе с longest_index, от которой она зависима, при каждом проходе цикла.

Итоговый корректный код:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>

  int main() {
      std::vector<std::string> some_vector = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
      int longest_index = 0;
      int current_index = 0;
      for (std::string el : some_vector) {
          int siz = some_vector[longest_index].size();
          int siz1 = el.size();
          if (siz1 > siz) {
              longest_index = current_index;
          }
          current_index += 1;
      }
      std::cout << "Longest string \"" << some_vector[longest_index] << "\" at index " << longest_index;
```

Comment: уточняйте у разработчиков/администраторов вашей проверяющей системы.

Comment: Может, я что упустил, но....   Вы изменяете индекс самой длинной строки, но не меняете переменную ```siz``` где сохраняете ее длину

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов спасибо, Вы правы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы работал через индексы, раз нужен индекс:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> some_vector = { "a", "b", "cc", "d", "e", "ff", "g" };
    size_t longest_index = 0, longest_size = some_vector[0].size();

    for (size_t current_index = 1; current_index < some_vector.size(); ++current_index)
        if (size_t siz; (siz = some_vector[current_index].size()) > longest_size) {
            longest_index = current_index;
            longest_size  = siz;
            }

    std::cout << "Longest string \"" << some_vector[longest_index] << "\" at index " << longest_index;
    }
```